# Как отобразить смежную часть круга?

Tags: html, css

Реализую некий блок.
Внутри блока должно быть 2 круга.
При этом, должна быть некая смежная часть круга.

Выглядеть, в идеале, должно как-то вот так:
[image: То, что мне нужно сделать]

Я смог добавить 2 круга (`.upper-circle` & `.bottom-circle`). Смежную область реализую в виде еще одного, дополнительного, третьего круга (`.inner-circle`).

Третий круг вложил в нижний.

Вроде и что-то получается, но ничего не получается. Я не могу понять, сама задумка правильная? Возможно, можно было сделать как-то проще..?
Ничего не понимаю.
Не понимаю как отобразить смежную часть круга, нормально, а не так, как у меня сейчас и как скрыть части круга, которые выходят за границу рамки...

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1%;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.main-block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 3%;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Margin-top section */
.mt-medium {
    margin-top: 4%;
}

.mt-larger {
    margin-top: 7%;
}
/* End margin-top section */

/* Block colors section */
.color-first-block {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(254,190,154,1) 0%, rgba(255,130,152,1) 100%);
}
/* End block colors section */

/* Circles-sections */
.upper-circle {
    width: 10%;
    height: 15%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24.5%;
    top: -0.5%;
    background: red;
}

.bottom-circle {
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
    background: yellowgreen;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-circle {
    width: 40%;
    height: 45%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: -3%;
    background: yellow;
}
/* End circles sections */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/styles.css">
    <title>Position medium</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- First block -->
        <div class="main-block color-first-block">
            <p>Weekly sales</p>
            <p class="mt-medium">$ 15.0000</p>
            <p class="mt-larger">Increased by 60%</p>

            <!-- circles section -->
            <div class="upper-circle"></div>
            <div class="bottom-circle">
                <div class="inner-circle"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- end circles section -->
        </div>
        <!-- End first block -->
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А почему это не могут быть просто два круга которые будут пересекаться, просто у каждого круга будет определенная прозрачность, что-то вроде `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сделайте два круга с прозрачностью и все. Заменил Ваши цвета на `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);` и немножко подогнал размеры для наглядности.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1%;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.main-block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 3%;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Margin-top section */
.mt-medium {
    margin-top: 4%;
}

.mt-larger {
    margin-top: 7%;
}
/* End margin-top section */

/* Block colors section */
.color-first-block {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(254,190,154,1) 0%, rgba(255,130,152,1) 100%);
}
/* End block colors section */

/* Circles-sections */
.upper-circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24.5%;
    top: -0.5%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.bottom-circle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    top: 20%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);

    overflow: hidden;
}
/* End circles sections */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/styles.css">
    <title>Position medium</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- First block -->
        <div class="main-block color-first-block">
            <p>Weekly sales</p>
            <p class="mt-medium">$ 15.0000</p>
            <p class="mt-larger">Increased by 60%</p>

            <!-- circles section -->
            <div class="upper-circle"></div>
            <div class="bottom-circle"></div>
            <!-- end circles section -->
        </div>
        <!-- End first block -->
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) буду учитывать это)